# Propositional logic proof check

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to re-learn first-order logic and so I've tried to prove the following statement

$$
(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow p \vee q
$$

I tried to begin like this using the [implication equivalence](http://www.math.csusb.edu/notes/logic/lognot/node2.html) twice:

\begin{array}
((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow q &\Leftrightarrow (\neg p \vee q) \rightarrow q\\
&\Leftrightarrow \neg (\neg p \vee q) \vee q\\
&\Leftrightarrow (p \wedge \neg q) \vee q
\end{array}

Then I used the [distributive property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/280857/241801):

\begin{array}
&\Leftrightarrow p \vee q \wedge \neg q \vee q
\end{array}

And because $(\neg q \vee q)$ is a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)), we can omit it in the formula:

\begin{array}
&\Leftrightarrow p \vee q
\end{array}

Is my reasoning correct? My logic skills have become really rusty as I've not seen in several years and I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: I think it's correct

Comment: correct answer...

Comment: @Muse_China Thank you too!

Comment: @Stefan Thank you, it's corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the comments of Mokata, Muse_China and Stefan, the proof is correct.

Comment: you can accept your own answer to close this case...

Comment: @draks... Unfortunately, only after two days

Answer (score 0):

An an additional 'brushing up your skills' exercise, you can also solve this using [logical equivalences involving conditional statements \ Rules (1) thru (8)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence).

The following are logical rewrites:

$(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow q \Leftrightarrow p \vee q$
$(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow q {\;\Leftrightarrow}^3\;\; \neg q \rightarrow p$
$\neg q \rightarrow \neg (p \rightarrow q) {\;\Leftrightarrow}^2\;\; \neg q \rightarrow p$
$\neg q \rightarrow (p \wedge \neg q) {\;\Leftrightarrow}^5\;\; \neg q \rightarrow p$
$(\neg q \rightarrow p) \wedge (\neg q \rightarrow \neg q) {\;\Leftrightarrow}^6\;\; \neg q \rightarrow p$

But $(\neg q \rightarrow \neg q)\;$ is $(q \vee \neg q)$ is TRUE, and so by the Identity Law we are left with

$\neg q \rightarrow p {\;\Leftrightarrow}\, \neg q \rightarrow p$