# Prove $\overline{A}\cap \left(A \cup \overline{B}\right) = \overline{A \cup B}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, boolean-algebra

How can I prove  $$\overline{A}\cap \left(A \cup \overline{B}\right) = \overline{A \cup B}$$ with boolean algebra? Honestly, I have absolutely no clue on how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been staring at this for hours and I just can't wrap my mind around how to solve it and what the answer is.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280844/using-the-distributivity-law-for-propositional-logic

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
A’\cap(A\cup B’) & = (A’\cap A) \cup (A’ \cap B’)\tag{distributive law}\\
 & = \emptyset \cup (A’ \cap B’)\\
 & = (A’ \cap B’)\\
 & = (A\cup B)’\tag{de Morgan}
\end{align*}
$$