# How to use distribution on (¬P∧R)∨(¬P∧¬Q)∨(R∧Q) to get the desired propositional formula?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am going through the accepted proof listed in a [previous thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092595/assistance-in-completing-the-proof-p-%E2%86%92-q%E2%88%A7q-%E2%86%92-r-is-equivalent-to-p-%E2%86%92-r%E2%88%A7/3092616?noredirect=1#comment6377108_3092616) and got stuck on a step where you use the distributivity property to go from:

(¬P∧R)∨(¬P∧¬Q)∨(R∧Q)

to:

(¬P∨¬P∨R)∧(¬P∨¬Q∨R)∧(¬P∨¬P∨Q)∧(¬P∨¬Q∨Q)∧(R∨¬P∨R)∧(R∨¬Q∨R)∧(R‌​∨¬P∨Q)∧(R∨¬Q∨Q)

Unfortunately, I was not able to understand how this was done.

Could someone show me the steps of how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just use the distributive law:

$$a\lor(b \land c)\equiv(a \lor b)\land(a \lor c)$$

Distributivity is analogous to distributivity of multiplication over addition: $$a \times (b + c) = a\times b + a\times c$$

For eg. in your case, we have

$$=(a \land b) \lor (c \land d) \lor (e \land f)$$
$$\equiv (a + b) \times (c + d) \times (e + f)$$ (consider symbolic change for understanding)

$$\equiv (a \times c \times e) + (a \times c \times f) + (a \times d \times e)+ (a \times d \times f) + (b \times c \times e) + (b \times c \times f)+ (b \times d \times e)+ (b \times d \times f)$$

which is exactly what is written as $$(\neg P \lor \neg P \lor R) \land (\neg P \lor \neg Q \lor R) \land (\neg P \lor \neg P \lor Q) \land (\neg P \lor \neg Q \lor Q) \land (R \lor \neg P \lor R) \land (R \lor \neg Q \lor R) \land (R \lor \neg P \lor Q) \land (R \lor \neg Q \lor Q)$$

Comment: See a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280844/using-the-distributivity-law-for-propositional-logic)